# How to load two packages?

Tags: packages, feyncalc

I want to use FeynArts and FormCalc. I've saved them in two different folders and I want to load and use both of them. This is how I load one of them: I write

```
SetDirectory["/Users/MyUserName/Library/Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/FeynArts-3.9"]
```

And then I write

```
<<FeynArts`
```

which then loads correctly. But now I want to load FormCalc which is in another folder. How can one load two packages lying in different folders?

My layman temporary solution is

```
SetDirectory["/Users/MyUserName/Library/Mathematica/Applications/\
HighEnergyPhysics/FeynArts-3.9"]
<< FeynArts`
SetDirectory["/Users/MyUserName/Library/Mathematica/Applications/\
HighEnergyPhysics/FormCalc-9.1"]
<< FormCalc`
```

Which I use to be able to run the script Lecture1-1.nb given on [Misho's webpage](http://www.misho-web.com/phys/feynlecture.html)

His script does not work on my Mac if I simply run it as it stands. 
If I simply write

```
<<FeynArts`
```

I get the error

```
Get::noopen: Cannot open FeynArts`. >>`
```

Comment: *In general*, packages need to be installed before loading them.  Usually this means placing them in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]`.  It is not necessary to enter the directory where the package is before loading it. Instead, install them to the correct location.  Now, I do not use FeynArts and FormCalc, so I do not know if there are any special steps needed when installing them.  Have you read the documentation of these packages, specifically the installation instructions?

Comment: How do I find the correct location?

Comment: Execute the `FileNameJoin[$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"]` in a notebook. That will show you the directory.

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" way to install FeynArts+FormCalc on OSX or Linux would be to use the automatic installation script from the developer. I'm quoting the second paragraph of [www.feynarts.de](http://www.feynarts.de)

> The automatic installation script gets you started quickly and easily.
>
> NEW Major improvements for Cygwin and Mac.
>
> Download the shell script [FeynInstall](http://www.feynarts.de/FeynInstall) [6 kB, MD5: 
>   7d10e00e95b07ba0cd5c396511db8a3b].
>
> (Use the right mouse button and "Save Link As...")
>
> Make it executable with `chmod 755 FeynInstall`.
>
> Run it in the directory in which you want the packages installed:   `./FeynInstall`.
>
> The script separately prompts you for the installation of FeynArts,  FormCalc, and LoopTools.
>
> ```
> Finally, it asks whether to include FeynArts and FormCalc in Mathematica's $Path
> ```

At the end you should be able to load both packages simply with

```
<<FeynArts`
<<FormCalc`
```

Comment: I don't know how closely this one is related but I though you may judge that quicker: [**138799**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138799/how-to-install-and-use-formcalc-and-looptools) thanks in advance ;)